# Regex to match a tag, skip a few, then match again

Tags: regex, powershell

I have xml files formatted like this:

```
<User>
<FirstName>Foo Bar</FirstName>
<LastName>Blah</LastName>
<OtherStuff>...</OtherStuff>
<More>...</More>
<CompanyName>Foo</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>bar@foo.com</EmailAddress>
</User>
<User>
...
```

I want to read through all xml files, creating as output `<FirstName>,<CompanyName>,<EmailAddress>`, so:

```
Foo Bar,Foo,bar@foo.com
Name,User2,user@email.com
FSds,Blah,blah@blah.com
```

I am using the following regex

```
(?si)<FirstName>(.*?)</FirstName>.*?<CompanyName>(.*?)</CompanyName>\s*<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>'
```

However, this returns also everything from the tags between `FirstName` and `CompanyName`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not consider a parser to perform this task?

Comment: I just need this quick and dirty approach to work because of a deadline :P Client is King and all that :-)

Comment: [No, you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171).

Answer (score 4):

Why not use XML processing?

```
C:\PS> $xml = [xml]@'
>>> <Users>
>>> <User>
>>> <FirstName>Foo Bar</FirstName>
>>> <LastName>Blah</LastName>
>>> <OtherStuff>...</OtherStuff>
>>> <More>...</More>
>>> <CompanyName>Foo</CompanyName>
>>> <EmailAddress>bar@foo.com</EmailAddress>
>>> </User>
>>> </Users>
>>> '@
C:\PS> "$($xml.Users.User.FirstName), $($xml.Users.User.CompanyName), $($xml.Users.User.EmailAddress)"
Foo Bar, Foo, bar@foo.com
```

You haven't shown the full XML document so I'm guessing on the top level nodes.  You will need to adjust based on the structure of your XML doc.

Comment: This is the quick and _easy_ approach for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I find multi-line regex can be easier if you build it in a here-string:

```
$String = @'
<User>
<FirstName>Foo Bar</FirstName>
<LastName>Blah</LastName>
<OtherStuff>...</OtherStuff>
<More>...</More>
<CompanyName>Foo</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>bar@foo.com</EmailAddress>
</User>
'@

$regex = @'
(?ms).+?<FirstName>(.+?)</FirstName>.*?
<CompanyName>(.+?)</CompanyName>.*?
<EmailAddress>(.+?)</EmailAddress>.+?
'@

$string -match $regex > $null
$matches[1..3] -join ','



Foo Bar,Foo,bar@foo.com
```

If it's a big file and you don't want to read it all in at once, you can use the closing tag as a delimiter:

```
Get-Content xmlfile.xml -Delimiter '</User>' |
 foreach {
  if ($_ -match $regex)
   {$matches[1..3] -join ','
   }
```